# The correct word to use in "the time that / in which / when"

Tags: grammar

In this sentence:

> It shows the time **...that/in which/when...** the job processing is
>   finished.

what is the correct word to use in instead of ...?

Comment: We ask our questioners to do a little homework themselves and we don't just do their homework for them. What do you think? And why?

Comment: @RonaldSole This is not a homework. This is a sentence from a paper I'm trying to write in english and since I'm not a native speaker, I face such a problems.

Comment: The question remains. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single correct answer to this question. It depends on the understanding in this context of the word **time**.

To say: **It shows the time THAT the job processing is finished** means it shows the moment that the processing is completed. In other words, the point in time.

The same meaning is captured by using **when**. It's an alternative to **that**.

To say: **It shows the time IN WHICH the job processing is finished** refers to the period of time that it takes to complete the job processing.

So all three uses are correct. If you are referring to the exact time, you may use either **that** or **when**.

If you mean the length of time, use **in which**.